# What is the difference between these below two program to copy content one directory to another?

Tags: shell-script, file-copy

Program number 1 ( Getting error )

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter source and destination directories: "
read $src $dest

if  [ -d $src ]  &&  [ -d $dest ]
then 
  echo "Process will start "
 else 
   echo "Enter valid directories"
   exit 1
 fi

 cp -r $src $dest

 status=$?

 if  [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then 
   echo "Successfully completed "

  else 
    echo "facing some problems "
fi
```

---

Second program ( not getting any error executing )

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Sourse Directory name : "

read src

echo "Enter destination directory: "

read dest

 if [ ! -d $src ]
    then 
    echo "Enter Valid Directory name "
    exit 1
elif [ ! -d $dest ]
     then
     echo "Enter Valid Destination source name "
      exit 2
fi 

cp -r $src $dest 

status=$?

if [ $status -eq 0 ]
then 
echo "File copied succesfully"
else 
echo "there is a problem"
fi
```

Comment: You could help everyone by listing the errors, showing how you execute the scripts, and any inputs you provide.

Comment: Welcome! In your code you have to account if `$src` and `$dest` are empty.

Answer (score 3):

One huge difference is under your eyes:

Program 1:

```
read $src $dest
```

Program 2:

```
read src
[...]
read dst
```

`read` is a shell builtin (see [manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)) provided variables names must **not** begin with `$`

Comment: How to take as arguments in this particular program? 
Will you help me with this

Comment: New question => new post... But this kind of question is very very simple to answer by googling 3 seconds.